# Highlight query-replace-regexp results while searching

Tags: regular-expressions, highlighting, query-replace-regexp

I am terrible at remembering regular expression syntax. When replacing in by buffer with a regexp, I would like Emacs to highlight the possible matches *while* I am typing the regexp, so that I can see on the fly whether I am getting what I want. Is there any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

I just noticed that my answer is valid for Emacs 29.0.50, but not for Emacs 28.1. Unfortunately, I can not easily find when this was added.

END EDIT

This is default behavior when using `M-x replace-regexp`.

Emacs does not show you the result when typing the new pattern (for replacement). However, when using [vim style substitution](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_and_replace) via the [evil]package, then you will also see a preview of the result of the replacement. You can also use it without using evil-mode, by installing and loading evil and then do `M-x evil-ex` (which you could bind to your preferred key).

Comment: It's nice that there is something that works on newer versions, but I am stuck with 26... Is it possible to use the evil-mode command without enabling the vim bindings?

Comment: Yes, for sure that's possible. Just install and load/require evil (without enabling evil-mode), subsequently you can use `M-x evil-ex` (I've also updated the answer). Of course, you can bind that command to your preferred keybinding